# python Win32 Save

Tags: python, win32com

I am using python to open an excel file and make some changes and then I need to save it. I can get everything done except the save part. How do I get python to save the file. If I save it manual I get the pop up box and I can click save, but I don't want to have to manually click save. I want python to just save it and close excel. I need help, this is what I have. but it won't work. I can get it to save but not close????

```
 import win32com.client
 import os


 xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
 xl.workbooks.open("C:\file.xlsm")
 xl.run("file.xlsm!macro")
 xl.Visible = True
 xl.save = true
 xl.close
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get a hook to the workbook object and apply the save as an argument to the close method:

```
xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.workbooks.open("C:\file.xlsm")
xl.run("file.xlsm!macro")
xl.Visible = True
wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
xl.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, plus getting the values for formulas,
this is what I did
(this part is after I put the formulas in from a different place and saved the      excel spreadsheet):

```
     import win32com.client as win

     xl=win.Dispatch('Excel.Application') 
     wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('filepath')
     xl.Visible = True
     wb.Close(SAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES)
     xl.Quit()
```

then when you open the spreadsheet or call:

```
     wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('filepath', data_only=True)
     ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
     print ws['A1'].value
```

it gives you the value of whatever is loaded using the formula, but you might need to add some

```
    time.sleep(sek)
```

to get it to wait for values to load before closing