# Openpyxl is not able to read function value refering to a cell which it wrote into previously

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a problem with openpyxl package. To illustrate the isue, I have prepared a simple example.

I have an excel file which contains nothing but formula `=A1` in `B1` cell. I would like to (1) write a value of 123 into cell `A1`, (2) save the workbook, (3) open it again and (4) read a content of cell `B1`. Instead of `123` I get `None`. Below you can find a simple code, which (I hope) should do as just described. Can anyone see, what I am doing wrong?

```
import openpyxl

# open file and select sheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# write value into cell A1
sheet['A1'].value = 123

# save the file and close it
wb.save('example.xlsx')
wb.close()

# open the file again and select sheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

# read value from cell containing referece to cell A1 => why it returns None?
print(sheet['B1'].value)

# close the file
wb.close()
```

Many thx,

Macky

PS: I am using python 3.5.5, openpyxl 2.5.6 and MS Office 2013 on Win7.

Comment: As written in the documentation: [openpyxl never evaluates formula](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=formula#using-formulae)

Comment: Or you use Xlwings to enter formulas rather than Openpyxl. Since that module does run Excel the formula(s) will be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openpyxl does not and will not calculate the result of formulas, hence the formula B1=A1 will only be calculated when you open the excel sheet or use another program that will calculate it. There are other libraries that I believe can help, like pycel.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting 'data_only' parameter to True while loading workbook.

```
wb = load_workbook("example.xlsx", data_only=True)
print(sheet['B1'].value)
```

This will print the result after computing formula at B1 cell.

Comment: As mentioned Openpyxl does not calculate forumals under any circumstances. It edits the unlying xml files that make up an xlsx file. There is no calculation engine involved.

Answer (score 0):

Since the above comments do not fully answer my question, I will add a link to another complementary [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622759/python-win32-save). Hopefully it will help others facing the same problem. I did not realize that the updated excel file has to be opened and saved using Excel application...

Regards,

Macky

Answer (score 0):

A feedback to @Jake Morris answer:

Yes, openpyxl doesn't have the capability till data to perform a recalculation operation on a excel file. But we can still solved the above problem by opening the excel file through a **COM object** via **win32com(pywin32)** library, where we can just do the following:

1. Open the excel file using *win32com(pywin32)* library.
2. Perform Recalculation operation using win32com(pywin32) *recalculate* function.
3. *Save*, *Close* and *Quite* the excel file.

If automatic recalculation is enabled in your excel file then you may skip step 2 and just perform step 1 and 3.

Thank you for your time

Velton Angelis D'silva

Comment: This works for me, using code:  `xl = win.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('path')
    xl.Calculate()
    xl.Visible = True
    wb.Close(SaveChanges=1)
    xl.Quit()`